# slam kinect packages

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Besides gmapping and RGBD SLAM, are there any other packages you can use for SLAM with the Kinect ?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65532/slam-kinect-packages/) by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2013-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Vslam (http://www.ros.org/wiki/vslam), but I wasn't able to install it. Maybe you'll be luckier! There's also Hector Mapping (http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping), but I read it doesn't work well with the Kinect (you would need a real laser scanner).

---

Originally posted by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) with karma: 343 on 2013-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0